# HTML/CSS code not pictured correctly or is their something wrong with my code?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. The following lines I wrote in the Atom text editor are not properly shown in the preview. The font is not changing from the default Times New Roman. Even after adding extra font-packages. However, I did not use any fancy kind of fonts. Is their something wrong with my code instead?

```css
body {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#point1 {
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: orange;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#point2 {
  font-family: Impact;
  color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#point3 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: pink;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#point4 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Text</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p> This is a paragraph. All of the text on this page has a font size of 16 pixels.
    This paragraph, like most of the text on this page is black and uses Tahoma font.</p>
  <ul>
    <li id="point1">This list item uses the Verdana font and color orange.</li>
    <li id="point2">This list item uses the Impact font and the color red.</li>
    <li id="point3">This list item uses the Georgia font and the color pink.</li>
    <li id="point4">This list item is black and uses the Tahoma font. It also contains a link to
      <link href="http://www.spiced-academy.com"></link>
    </ul>
  <p>This is another paragraph. Each item in the list above has a top and bottom
    margin of 10 pixels.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, even with the the HTML structure which is slighly broken (you have an unclosed `li`).

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Gonna fix that missing *li*

Comment: Problem is, if you can't reproduce the issue, we're not going to be able to help much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is the problem but try to add the attribute type on the link css stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the code preview window I see it works (Chrome, Mac). Try to clear your browser cache or write `font-family: Tahoma !Important;`

Comment: Doesn't my advice work for you? (clear cache or add !important to code)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your CSS page is saved as `stylesheet.css` because this is what is referenced in your code.

Check that your HTML file and CSS file are saved in the same directory.

For testing, you could have the CSS in a `<style>` tag, before even trying to link to a stylesheet. You can place this in the `<head>` tag. Then tackle the external stylesheet once you can successfully see the styles here.

```
<head>
  <style>

    body {
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    #point1 {
      font-family: Verdana;
      color: orange;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

   #point2 {
     font-family: Impact;
     color: red;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
   }

   #point3 {
     font-family: Georgia;
     color: pink;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

   #point4 {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   }

  </style>
</head>
```